# Removing Overlapping Outlines Within a Single Feature Class

Tags: polygon, boundaries, geology, outline

I have a polygon feature that is overlapping itself. Both of the polygons in the image below are from that same feature. I do not want to dissolve the boundaries, but I only want one of the outlines to present. They also have different line styles for their outlines, so I want to be able to choose which one presents depending on the contact.

Ex. - Polgyon A overlaps Polygon B and Polygon C. At the contacts, I want Polygon A's outline to present at contact with Polygon B, but at Polygon A's contact with Polygon C, I want Polygon C's outline to present.

[image: 0]

Comment: That isn't the way ArcGIS is designed to work. Either you append and dissolve, or the features are independent; you can't have it both ways.

Comment: Please say explicitly what software you are using, and add a tag with it (other users who follow the tag for ArcGIS for example will receive an e-mail about questions with ArcGIS tag). Otherwise you may get answers that will not help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps: Split it out by polygon ID, use the different polygons to clip one another, and merge the results as a new polygon?